# Having Thursday and Wednesday as Start and end date of the week for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a bit of struggle converting the start and end date of the week into Thursday and Wednesday into SQL Server.

I have figured out to get a code to extract the Thursday and Wednesday of the week

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 3) ThursdayOfCurrentWeek
```

however the issue is that the current Thursday's week start should be itself but the code returns the Thursday from last week.

For example, preferably it should be:

```
29/09/2021 (23/09/2021-29/09/2021);
30/09/2021 (30/09/2021-06/09/2021)
```

but SQL will return:

```
29/09/2021 (23/09/2021-29/09/2021);
30/09/2021 (23/09/2021-29/09/2021)
```

Is there a way that I could do this?

Comment: You could `SET` the value of [`DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) at the start of your batch. Alternatively (and possibly better) invest the time in creating a calendar table; they are an invaluable resource on any instance.

Answer (score 0):

..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=6da01361711acee6ce46772dccd0ac6e)..

```
select 
  _date, datename(weekday, _date) _dateweekday, 
  prvthursday, datename(weekday, prvthursday),
  cast(prvthursday as date) as week_start, cast(dateadd(day, 6, prvthursday) as date) as week_end
from
(
select *, dateadd(day, -(7+datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst, _date))-5/*<-- prev thursday:5, prev sat:7, prev monday:2 etc*/)%7, _date) as prvthursday
from
(
  --dates
  select dateadd(day, row_number() over(order by @@spid), '20210101') as _date
  from sys.all_objects
) as d
) as src;
```